# How can an authenticated user access the drive that is publicly accessible?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, asp.net-core-5.0

With this code, I am able to get the files that have been shared to the `service account` email.

But, when I shared the folder (that was not owned by me, but is publicly accessible) from a different email it is not displayed in the list.

Is there any way an authenticated user can access the drive folder that is publicly accessible, but which I won't own?

```
var serviceAccountEmail = "";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(_credentialsService.GetCredentialPath(), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
   {
       Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
   }.FromCertificate(certificate));


var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
});
```

Getting Drive Details

```
 Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest FileListRequest = service.Files.List();

// for getting folders only.
//FileListRequest.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
FileListRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
FileListRequest.Corpora = "allDrives";
FileListRequest.Q = "sharedWithMe";
FileListRequest.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
FileListRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;

// List files.
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = FileListRequest.Execute().Files;
List<GoogleDriveFile> FileList = new List<GoogleDriveFile>();
```

Sharing Process:

I shared the file to the service account email, from my personal google email.

[image]

And See it is still not available, the image that I owned only is shared. Which is my problem.

[image]

Comment: **But, when I shared the folder (that was not owned by me, but is publicly accessible) from a different email it is not displayed in the list.**  <-- can you clerify that statment.  Did you or did you not share the folder with the service account directly?

Comment: Yes, I share that public folder with the email that ends with `*iam.gserviceaccount.com`, from the email account that I created. But the code doesn't show in my shared folder.

Comment: if you shared it property then the folder should be available to the service account.   Remove the Q pram and see what happens. actually try removing all the extra parms.  just to test.

Comment: still got only the one file that I owned and that I shared with the service account. the public folder is still not seen `FileListRequest.Execute().Files`

Comment: Then it wasnt shared.  Go to google drive and share the directory with the service account like you would share it with a normal user.

Comment: I am confused by your question... You shared the folder with the service account, but want to access it as an authenticated user rather than as the service account? If you share it with the service account, you need to authenticate as the service account to see the folder in your "sharedWithMe" list; If you share the folder with a specific user - then you need to authenticate as the respective user to see the folder. Btw, if it is a public folder, any user can see it from the UI as long as he types into his browser the  URL of this folder.

Comment: `You shared the folder with the service account, but want to access it as an authenticated user rather than as the service account?`
- NO! I shared the folder with the service account, I wanted to access it as a service account.  `user can see it from the UI as long as he types into his browser the URL of this folder`, yes I can see it in the UI, But I want to see the details through the API.

Answer (score 0):

### Sending the link of a publicly viewable file is not the same as sharing the file

Your screen looks like this:

---

[image]

---

- This means that you have view-only access to the file
- If you had edit access to the file, the screen would look as following:

---

[image]

---

- Thus, since you are not an editor of the public file, you cannot add another viewer / editor to this file and consecuently it will not appear in the `sharedWithMe` of the user to whom you sent the email - no matter if this user is an actual suer or a service account

**Solution:**

If you need to explicitly share the file with the service account, your options are

- to obtain edit access to the public file (if feasible)
- create a copy of the respective file onto your own Drive (if copying is not disabled) and share your version explicitly with the service account

Comment: isn't there a way to access the file and folder which is accessible publicly, without sharing that with the service account?

Comment: It is accessible from the UI via the share link, but you cannot access programmatically a file that has not been shared explicitly with the user  - until the user opens this file once from the UI (otherwise, just imagine all public files in the world would come up in your "sharedWithMe" list). Unfortunately, a service account  cannot open a file from the UI, however, if you know the file id (which you do), you can access the file programamtically with the method [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get).

Comment: this example is in v2, is it same in v3 as well?

Comment: Yes, just refer to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get instead of https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get.

Comment: with the way mentioned in this URL, I am able to get the details of the folder, but I am not able to loop through the content inside the folder

Comment: Well no, unless you get the files within this folder sequentially by their id, the only options would be the two I mentioned in my answer - unfortunately there is no different way for a service account.